# Is there a way to tile editors in Eclipse using only the keyboard?

Tags: eclipse, editor, tiling

When working on multiple files in Eclipse, I usually organize the editors in tiles. However, there are times, when I need to close all open editors to open a different set of files. When I open the new batch however, it defaults to stacking all editors in one single tile. I want the layout to be mostly constant, or changeable through shortcut keys. Maybe close to what AwesomeWM, ion3, etc. do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those familiar with emacs, you can install the [emacs+](http://www.mulgasoft.com/) plugin, which implements window splitting (C-x 2, C-x 3) and many other related window/buffer operations. Works great for my needs. I don't think the built-in emacs scheme does this.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think so. There is no such option in eclipse. You need to use mouse to do it.